# Eliminar un elemento en un vector en C

Tags: c

He desarrollado este algoritmo que carga, muestra y elimina elementos en un vector. Pero cuando le doy a eliminar un elemento, sólo elimina el último y no el que elijo. Por ejemplo, ingreso los elementos: 4, 5, 6; y luego digo que quiero eliminar el 4 o el 5 y se elimina el 6, o sea siempre el último.

Uso CodeBlocks en Windows. Realmente no le encuentro la falla. ¿Qué es lo que está pasando?¿Y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Aquí dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM 30

void CargarVector(int arr[TAM], int cantidad);
void MostrarVector(int arr[TAM], int cantidad);
void EliminarElemento(int arr[TAM], int *cantidad, int elem);

int main(){
    int option;
    int arr[TAM];
    int cantidad;
    int elem;

    do{
        printf("Menu\n");
        printf("-----\n");
        printf("0: Salir\n");
        printf("1: Cargar vector\n");
        printf("2: Mostar vector\n");
        printf("3: Eliminar vector\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch(option){
            case 1: printf("Cuantos elementos desea ingresar?"); scanf("%d", &cantidad);
                    CargarVector(arr, cantidad); break;
            case 2: MostrarVector(arr, cantidad); break;
            case 3: printf("Ingrese elemento a eliminar: "); scanf("%d", &elem);
                    EliminarElemento(arr, &cantidad, elem); break;
        }
    } while(option!=0);

    return 0;
}

void CargarVector(int arr[TAM], int cantidad){
    int i;

    for(i= 0; i<cantidad; i+=1){
        printf("Ingrese elemento: "); scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
}

void MostrarVector(int arr[TAM], int cantidad){
    int i;
    for(i= 0; i<cantidad; i+=1){
        printf("Elemento[%d]= %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}

void EliminarElemento(int arr[TAM], int *cantidad, int elem){
    int i;

    for(i= elem; i<*cantidad-1; i+=1){
        arr[i]= arr[i+1];
    }
    *cantidad-=1;
}
```

Comment: quizas no entendi su error pero lo acabo de compilar y funciona o eso creo, yo añado 3 numero y los borro aleatoriamente y funciona, eso es lo que usted espera que pase, si es eso igual tiene que hacer un rebulid, porque igual esta ejecutando otra version de programa. Saludos

Comment: No no se que pasa, a mi solo me elimina el ultimo elemento, y no se por que, es un algoritmo sencillo pero no le encuentro la falla, por ejemplo, tambien ingreso los elementos: 4, 5, 6; y luego digo que quiero eliminar el 4 o el 5 y se elimina el 6, o sea siempre el ultimo. Uso CodeBlocks en Windows. Realmente no le encuentro la falla!

Comment: Realmente no estás eliminando ningún elemento. Simplemente estás copiando a partir de cierta posición en adelante (y a veces nada, como en el ejemplo de 4,5,6)

Answer (score 8):

El problema es que el parametro `elem` es el elemento y no la posición en la que se encuentra el elemento. El algoritmo funcionaría bien si en lugar de preguntar "Ingrese elemento a eliminar: " lo que preguntaras fuese: "Ingrese **la posición del elemento** a eliminar: ".

Realmente no se está eliminando ningún elemento en sí. Vamos a ver el código de `EliminarElemento`:

```
void EliminarElemento(int arr[TAM], int *cantidad, int elem){
    int i;

    for(i= elem; i<*cantidad-1; i+=1){
        arr[i]= arr[i+1];
    }
    *cantidad-=1;
}
```

Lo que esta función hace:

- A partir de la posición especificada por elemento.
- Mueve todos los elementos una posición.
- Reduce el tamaño del vector en 1.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso de [4,5,6] en particular, el problema es que el elemento 4 no está en la posición 4 del vector sino en la posición cero. Con lo cual lo que hace tu algoritmo es: nada. Porque el bucle `for` es desde la posición 4 y hasta que la posición sea menor que 3. No entra nunca. Pero la variable cantidad (el número de elementos en el vector) se reduce en uno, por lo que el nuevo vector es [4,5]. Incluso cuando indicaste que borrara el elemento 4, se "borra" el 6.

Answer (score 1):

igual debe de hacer un rebuild igual esta usando una compilacion anterior, si entiendo bien lo que quiere lograr esto es lo que obtengo:

```
Menu
-----
0: Salir
1: Cargar vector
2: Mostar vector
3: Eliminar vector
1
Cuantos elementos desea ingresar?3
Ingrese elemento: 4 
Ingrese elemento: 5
Ingrese elemento: 6
Menu
-----
0: Salir
1: Cargar vector
2: Mostar vector
3: Eliminar vector
2
Elemento[0]= 4
Elemento[1]= 5
Elemento[2]= 6
Menu
-----
0: Salir
1: Cargar vector
2: Mostar vector
3: Eliminar vector
3
Ingrese elemento a eliminar: 1
Menu
-----
0: Salir
1: Cargar vector
2: Mostar vector
3: Eliminar vector
2
Elemento[0]= 4
Elemento[1]= 6
Menu
-----
0: Salir
1: Cargar vector
2: Mostar vector
3: Eliminar vector
```

Comment: se publica como muestra

Comment: Muchas gracias! estaba bien, estaba confundido mal, posición con elemento, ya me di cuenta porque no funcionaba, muchas gracias !

Comment: @Fesa usted estaba introduciendo el numero que queria "eliminar" y no la posicion donde estaba.Saludos